# USMT loadstate - how to resolve this error

Tags: windows-11, migration, usmt

I am using USMT from the current ADK to migrate a user from an offline drive. The drive came from a Win 10 machine, the target machine is Win 11.

I have got scanstate to run without errors.

```
&".\scanstate.exe" C:\USMT /ue:E* /ui:USER /offlinewindir:E:\Windows /progress:C:\Windows\Temp\USMT-progress.log /O /v:5 /i:MigUser.xml /i:MigApp.xml /i:MigDocs.xml /Listfiles:C:\Windows\Temp\migrated-files.txt /l:C:\Windows\Temp\scanstate.log
```

When I try to run loadstate, however, I get the following error in the log:

```
2023-04-28 17:23:55, Info                  [0x080000]     V2VArbitrate: Source migration unit <S-1-5-80-3263513310-3392720605-1798839546-683002060-3227631582>\Microsoft-Windows-TextServicesFramework-Migration (CCSIAgent) is not supported on the destination machine and it will not be restored
2023-04-28 17:23:55, Error                 [0x080000]     V2VArbitrate: Source migration unit is critical, arbitration will fail[gle=0x000003f0]
2023-04-28 17:23:55, Error                 [0x000000]     V2V Arbitration failed. Last error: 0x00000032[gle=0x00000032]
```

The loadstate command is:

```
&".\loadstate.exe" C:\USMT /ue:* /mu:USER:DOMAIN\ENNNN /progress:C:\Windows\Temp\USMT-progress.log /c /v:5 /i:MigApp.xml /i:MigDocs.xml /l:C:\Windows\Temp\loadstate.log
```

Is there any way to resolve this error?